# Google AppEngine Domain aliasing and instances

Tags: php, google-app-engine

In my current hosting, each url is a stand-alone project in a separate folder.

example.com/-> Website project

example.com/admin -> Admin Panel project

example.com/demo -> App Demo project

So, each url should point to a different project in AppEngine.

How do I configure that when there's no global .htaccess?

Comment: You should specify which language you use. From the .htaccess part I am guessing PHP ?

Comment: yes indeed, I'm using 3 Codeigniter for some projects, and a custom framework for another one

Comment: Did you have a look at this ? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map a Google App Engine project to some URL path, only to a subdomain. So you could map www.example.com, admin.example.com, and demo.example.com to different GAE apps, and make your naked domain(example.com) redirect to www.example.com.

If this is not possible, maybe you can use a proxy or CDN to root the requests differently depending on the URL, but this is harder to maintain and you would loose the auto-scalibility features of GAE.

Comment: yeah, I guess this can only be solved using subdomains